# hasOne association using Sequelize does not work when using the .ejs template to display data

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have defined a one-to-one relationship between the Customer table and the Address table using ORM Sequelize

The source code for Customer.js is as follows:

```
// One to One Relationship

// Customer.js
// Include Sequelize module. 
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Datatypes = require('Sequelize');
const path = require("path");


// Import sequelize object, 
// Database connection pool managed by Sequelize. 
// Import db_sequelize
const db_sequelize = require(path.join(__dirname,'..','config','db_sequelize.js'));


const Customer = db_sequelize.define('Customer', { 

    customer_id:{ 

        // Sequelize module has INTEGER Data_Type. 
        type:Datatypes.INTEGER, 

        // To increment user_id automatically. 
        autoIncrement:true, 

        // user_id can not be null. 
        allowNull:false, 

        // For uniquely identify user. 
        primaryKey:true
    }, 

    first_name: { type: Datatypes.STRING, allowNull:true }, 

    last_name: { type: Datatypes.STRING, allowNull:true }, 

    email: { type: Datatypes.STRING, allowNull:true},

    address_id: { type: Datatypes.INTEGER, allowNull:true},


    // dates => current time 
    myDate: { type: Datatypes.DATE, 
        defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW }, 

    // Timestamps 
    createdAt: Datatypes.DATE, 
    updatedAt: Datatypes.DATE, 
}); 

// Exporting Customer, using this constant 
// we can perform CRUD operations on 
// 'Customer' table. 
console.log(Date() + " " + "Model Customer has been defined");
module.exports = Customer;
```

The source code for Address.js is as follows:

```
// Address.js
// Include Sequelize module. 
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Datatypes = require('sequelize');
const path = require("path");


// Import sequelize object, 
// Database connection pool managed by Sequelize. 
// Import db_sequelize
const db_sequelize = require(path.join(__dirname,'..','config','db_sequelize.js'));


const Address = db_sequelize.define('Address', { 

    address_id:{ 

        // Sequelize module has INTEGER Data_Type. 
        type:Datatypes.INTEGER, 

        // To increment user_id automatically. 
        autoIncrement:true, 

        // user_id can not be null. 
        allowNull:false, 

        // For uniquely identify user. 
        primaryKey:true
    }, 

    address: { type: Datatypes.STRING, allowNull:true }, 

    postal_code: { type: Datatypes.STRING, allowNull:true }, 

    district: { type: Datatypes.STRING, allowNull:true},

    // dates => current time 
    myDate: { type: Datatypes.DATE, 
            defaultValue: Datatypes.NOW }, 

    // Timestamps 
    createdAt: Datatypes.DATE, 
    updatedAt: Datatypes.DATE, 
});

const Customer = require(path.join(__dirname,'..','models', 'Customer.js'));


// 1:1 Relation between Customer and Address
// Each Customer has only One Address

Customer.hasOne(Address, {
    foreignKey: {
        name: 'address_id'
    }
});
Address.belongsTo(Customer, {
    foreignKey: 'address_id'
});

// Exporting Address, using this constant 
// we can perform CRUD operations on 
// 'Address' table. 
console.log(Date() + " " + "Model Address has been defined");
module.exports = Address;
```

When displaying the address value associated with the customer, the address is displayed correctly without using the .ejs template

```
// TEST ONE TO ONE RELATIONSHIP
// Get Customer address for customer_id equal 1
let  get_address_customer_id = async function(){
  try {
      let customer = await Customer.findByPk(1);
      // find by primary key
      let customerAddress = await customer.getAddress();
      //Address belongs to Customer
      //then customer.getAddress();
      //get the address
      //for customer_id equal 1
      console.log("NUI del Customer    : ", customer.customer_id);
      console.log("Customer Name : ", customer.first_name + " " + customer.last_name);
      console.log("Customer Address  : ", customerAddress.address);      
  } catch (error) { console.error("Error log", error);}
}

get_address_customer_id();
```

NUI del Customer    :  1

Customer Name :  First name 1 Last name 1

Customer Address  :  Address 1

However, when using the .ejs template the one to one relationship between Customer and Address is not working. In the one to one relationship test I use let customerAddress = await customer.getAddress(); However, I do not use this in the .ejs template, I assume this is the difference. However it is assumed that if the 1 to 1 relationship works you should get the address linked to the customer

[image]

```
// list_customers.js

// Set router
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const path = require("path");

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {    
    
    //Get the model for Customer
    const Customer = require(path.join(__dirname,'..', 'models', 'Customer.js'));

    // Find all Customers
    const customers = await Customer.findAll();

    res.render("view_listar_customers.ejs", { model: customers });


});

module.exports = router;
```

The .ejs template code to display the relationship data between Customer and Address is as follows:

```
    <tbody>
      <% for (const customer of model) { %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= customer.customer_id %></td>
          <td><%= customer.first_name %>, <%= customer.last_name %></td>
          <td><%= customer.address %></td>
          <td class="d-print-none">
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" href="/edit_customer/<%= customer.customer_id %>">Edit</a>
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="/delete_customer/<%= customer.customer_id %>">Delete</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <% } %>
    </tbody>
```

A guide to solve the problem would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative to display the data using Sequelize's Raw Queries. I attach the source code section in case it is useful for someone who wants to display the result of a query of all the records using a one to one relationship with ORM Sequelize and have the results displayed in a .ejs template.

For the implementation of the One to One relationship, the following documentation was used. Thanks to Allan James Lapid
SEE: https://gist.github.com/ajLapid718/ca67efc0360c617e5eebb6f1342ae53e

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {    
    
    //Get the model for Customer and Address
    const Customer = require(path.join(__dirname,'..', 'models', 'Customer.js'));
    const Address = require(path.join(__dirname,'..', 'models', 'Address.js'));


    const db_sequelize = require(path.join(__dirname, '..','config', 'db_sequelize.js'));

    // Inner Join
    const [customers, metadata] = await db_sequelize.query(
    "SELECT C.first_name, C.last_name, A.address FROM Customer C INNER JOIN Address A ON C.AddressId=A.id");
                                                          
    // Display Clients with their addresses
    res.render("view_listar_customers.ejs", { model: customers });


});
```

Address.js

```
//Address.js
// Include Sequelize module. 
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Datatypes = require('sequelize');
const path = require("path");


///Import db_sequelize
const db_sequelize = require(path.join(__dirname,'..','config','db_sequelize.js'));


const Address = db_sequelize.define('Address', { 

    id:{ 

        // Sequelize module has INTEGER Data_Type. 
        type:Datatypes.INTEGER, 

        // To increment user_id automatically. 
        autoIncrement:true, 

        allowNull:false, 

        // For uniquely identify user. 
        primaryKey:true
    }, 

    address: { type: Datatypes.STRING, allowNull:true }, 

    postal_code: { type: Datatypes.STRING, allowNull:true }, 

    district: { type: Datatypes.STRING, allowNull:true},

    // dates => current time 
    myDate: { type: Datatypes.DATE, 
            defaultValue: Datatypes.NOW }, 

    // Timestamps 
    createdAt: Datatypes.DATE, 
    updatedAt: Datatypes.DATE, 
});


// Exporting Address, using this constant 
// we can perform CRUD operations on 
// 'Address' table. 
console.log(Date() + " " + "Model Address has been defined");
module.exports = Address;
```

Customer.js

```
//Customer.js
// Include Sequelize module. 
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Datatypes = require('Sequelize');
const path = require("path");


///Import db_sequelize
const db_sequelize = require(path.join(__dirname,'..','config','db_sequelize.js'));


const Customer = db_sequelize.define('Customer', { 

    id:{ 

        // Sequelize module has INTEGER Data_Type. 
        type:Datatypes.INTEGER, 

        // To increment user_id automatically. 
        autoIncrement:true, 

        // user_id can not be null. 
        allowNull:false, 

        // For uniquely identify user. 
        primaryKey:true
    }, 

    first_name: { type: Datatypes.STRING, allowNull:true }, 

    last_name: { type: Datatypes.STRING, allowNull:true }, 

    email: { type: Datatypes.STRING, allowNull:true},

    // dates => current time 
    myDate: { type: Datatypes.DATE, 
            defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW }, 

    // Timestamps 
    createdAt: Datatypes.DATE, 
    updatedAt: Datatypes.DATE, 
}); 

// Exporting Customer, using this constant 
// we can perform CRUD operations on 
// 'Customer' table. 
console.log(Date() + " " + "Model Customer has been defined");
module.exports = Customer;
```

app.js

```
Address.hasOne(Customer);
Customer.belongsTo(Address);
```

> Note that the AddressId metadata is created in the Customer table

[image]

[image]

view:

```
      <% for (const customer of model) { %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= customer.first_name %>
        <td><%= customer.last_name %></td>
        <td><%= customer.address %></td>
        ...
      </tr>
      <% } %>
```